# How do I run multiple nginx instances on the same server?

Tags: services, nginx

How do I run multiple nginx instances on the same server?

This is useful when you need to stop a specific instance while leaving other instances running.

What should `/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx-instance2.service` contain if it is possible just to create multiple services?

Comment: I'm no expert, but maybe containers?

Comment: Containers are a really good solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

This will be a short answer outlining the concepts I use.

Install each of your [nginx instances](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) in a container (for instance Docker). You can then choose which port get exposed for each instance.

Access each instance on their specific port *or* set up a reverse proxy to receive all incoming HTTP and HTTPS request (for instance [Traefik](https://hub.docker.com/_/traefik)).

Configure your proxy so that each domain and subdomain point to a specific nginx instance, running on each port. Examples

```
sub1.domain1.com --> nginx instance 1 (e.g. 10.10.10.10:8877)
sub2.domain1.com --> nginx instance 2 (e.g. 10.10.10.10:8888)
sub1.domain2.com --> nginx instance 3 (e.g. 10.10.10.10:8899)

---  Etc. ---
```

The exact configuration will depend on your choice of software for the tasks.